# How to show another window from mainwindow in QT

Tags: windows, qt, showdialog

Platform: QT, Windows XP

I am new to Qt. I want to show another window(what to do to open it as dialog) from `mainwindow`. I did "`add New Item ->Qt Designer Form Class`", named it say `MyWindow`. But how to show this `MyWindow` from `mainwindow` ?

Answer (score 58):

1. Implement a slot in your QMainWindow where you will open your new Window,
2. Place a widget on your QMainWindow,
3. Connect a signal from this widget to a slot from the QMainWindow (for example: if the widget is a QPushButton connect the signal `click()` to the QMainWindow custom slot you have created).

Code example:

**MainWindow.h**

```
// ...
include "newwindow.h"
// ...
public slots:
   void openNewWindow();
// ...
private:
   NewWindow *mMyNewWindow;
// ...
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
// ...
   MainWindow::MainWindow()
   {
      // ...
      connect(mMyButton, SIGNAL(click()), this, SLOT(openNewWindow()));
      // ...
   }
// ...
void MainWindow::openNewWindow()
{
   mMyNewWindow = new NewWindow(); // Be sure to destroy your window somewhere
   mMyNewWindow->show();
   // ...
}
```

This is an example on how display a custom new window. There are a lot of ways to do this.