# How to use QmainWindow inside a QWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am facing a problem, I have created an application using QmainWindow it is having tool bars, & statusbars. Now I have to add this application to another application which is derived from a another QMainWindow . Now I want to have my main Window inside this Main Window . How to do this Can we have QMainWindow inside Another QmainWindow or inside a QWidget?
please hepl me .

Comment: So, you are trying to open a new window from your application? If so, you can follow these posts, they helped me a lot in achieving that:
http://247jules.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/how-to-open-a-new-window-in-qt/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518317/how-to-show-another-window-from-mainwindow-in-qt

Comment: "Inside" as in having two separate main windows, or really a mainwindow nested in another window?

Comment: I want a nested mainwindow inside a mainwindow.

Comment: What's a problem? Create an instance of your previously created QMainwindow subclass and place it on your second application's window layout.

Answer (score 7):

I would write something like:

QMainWindow inside of another QMainWindow

```
QMainWindow *mainWindow = new QMainWindow;
QMainWindow *subWindow = new QMainWindow(mainWindow);
// .. some configuration
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(subWindow);
```

QMainWindow inside of a QWidget

```
QWidget *mainWindow = new QWidget;
QMainWindow *subWindow = new QMainWindow(mainWindow);
// .. some configuration
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(subWindow);
mainWindow->setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: For anyone chancing on this, you might want to also have `subWindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);`, `QMainWindow` by default has its window flag as `Qt::Window` which can cause some niggling issues.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this:

```
void QApplication::setActiveWindow(QWidget * active)
```

to set the widget (your main window) as the main window.