# Display QWindow in a MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to render a QOpenGLContext to a QWindow. The goal is to use this QWindow in another MainWindow. Is it possible to display a QWindow inside another Qt program's MainWindow?

Comment: I think you can't, but maybe you can use a QWidget instead of the inner QWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are trying to open an extra window from your application's MainWindow, you could check [this post](http://247jules.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/how-to-open-a-new-window-in-qt/), it is a nice guide on the topic. Also [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518317/how-to-show-another-window-from-mainwindow-in-qt) could help.

In his comment, @Samoth told you that's not possible to open a window *inside* another one, and he's right. But I think that you only want to open a new window *from* the starting one (in that case, see the links above).