# QML - How to have a popup that doesn't get clipped

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I need to have a Popup that stays visible outside the bounds of the main window.
I couldn't find anything in the Qt documentation.

This is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: popup.open()
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 300
        height: 400
        modal: true
        focus: true
        dim: false

        contentItem: Rectangle
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "red"
        }

        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
    }
}
```

This is the output of this:
[image]

I want the red to go beyond the window borders.
Something like this:
[image]

I'd appreciate the help!

Note: using a Dialog is no good for me.

Comment: Ok, I see you've copied the code from the documentation page. So you have to check the paragraph below that, especially the top/left insets. Actually you set x,y properties as 100,100 and so QML does exactly you asked to do. if you want it in the window borders, change it to 0,0

Comment: @folibis I need the red to go outside the window. I added an image to illustrate.

Comment: I think you want to [open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518317/how-to-show-another-window-from-mainwindow-in-qt)

Answer (score 2):

Popups are not proper windows, so you'd need to create a new window like Michael mentioned:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ApplicationWindow {
        id: redWindow
        x: mainWindow.x + mainWindow.width / 2
        y: mainWindow.y + mainWindow.height / 2
        width: 300
        height: 400
        flags: Qt.Popup | Qt.Dialog
        visible: true

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

There is a suggestion to make Popups proper windows [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69558).

Comment: All right, this is what I needed to hear. It can't be done with Popups (for now).